# Where is the numerical solving breaking down?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, boundary-condition-at-infinity, precision-and-accuracy

I am working with a set of three coupled reaction-diffusion PDEs, and for some parameter values I am getting some not so great solutions. I have been searching documentation and tutorials, and I have been trying to implement various methods and change various settings, but I feel like I am just blindly trying things without fully understanding what is going on. The equations might look intimidating, but I have supplied my code as well to help make everything reproducible.

As a summary, I was asking about why a bad solution is obtained for a certain parameter set. As I went through testing my problem to make this post I came across a second issue where the solution behavior also depended on the end time of integration, which seems odd to me. Why am I running into these issues?

---

## Equations

The set of equations I am working with is as follows:
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=\left(1+\frac{\gamma_{pL}\cdot y_T}{(1+\gamma_P\cdot x)^2}\right)^{-1}\cdot\left[\gamma_{D_P}\cdot\nabla^2x+\gamma_a\cdot x_I+\gamma_c\cdot\frac{\gamma_{pL}}{\gamma_P}\cdot\left(\frac{\gamma_P\cdot x}{1+\gamma_P\cdot x}\right)^2\cdot y_T\right]$$

$$\frac{\partial y_T}{\partial t}=-\gamma_c\cdot\frac{\gamma_P\cdot x}{1+\gamma_P\cdot x}\cdot y_T$$

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}=\left(1+\frac{\gamma_R}{(1+\gamma_L\cdot z)^2}\right)^{-1}\cdot\left[\gamma_{D_L}\cdot\nabla^2z+\gamma_c\cdot\frac{\gamma_P\cdot x}{1+\gamma_P\cdot x}\cdot y_T\right]$$

where $x$, $y_T$, and $z$ are functions of $r$ (polar coordinate) and $t$ (time), $x_I$ is a source term given by
$$x_I=\frac{1}{2\cdot\gamma_{D_P}\cdot t+1}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2\cdot(2\cdot\gamma_{D_P}\cdot t+1)}-\gamma_a\cdot t\right)$$
and all $\gamma_i$ terms are parameters.

Initial conditions and boundary conditions are as follows:
$$x(r,0)=z(r,0)=0,\ y_T(r,0)=1$$
$$\left.\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right|_{r=0}=\left.\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\right|_{r=0}=0$$
$$x(\infty,0)=z(\infty,0)=0$$

In words, we start off with no $x$ and $z$, and $y_T$ starts at a maximum value of $1$ across all space. The no-flux boundary condition at the origin is because the system has radial symmetry, and we want $x$ and $z$ to go to $0$ at $\infty$.

---

## Code

To tweak the above equations to work nicely in Mathematica (I think?), we need to use a "large" value of $r$ in place of $\infty$ and we need to use a point close to $r=0$ rather than $r=0$ itself (due to the $1/r$ term in the Laplacian in polar coordinates).

```
dr = .001; (*"small" r since we cannot use the origin in polar coordinates*)
ρFar = 100.; (*r that is "infinity"*)
τmax = 6.38;(*time to solve out to*)
```

The equations above:

```
xI = 1/(2*γDP*t + 1)*Exp[-(r-dr)^2/(2*(2*γDP*t + 1)) - γa*t];

dx = D[x[r, t],t] == (1 + (γpL*yT[r, t])/(1 + γP*x[r,t])^2)^-1*(γDP*Laplacian[x[r, t], {r, θ}, "Polar"] + γa*xI + γc*γpL/γP*((γP*x[r, t])/(1 + γP*x[r, t]))^2*yT[r, t]);

dyT = D[yT[r, t], t] == (-γc*γP*x[r, t]*yT[r, t])/(1 + γP*x[r, t]);

dz = D[z[r, t],t] == (1 + γR/(1 + γL*z[r, t])^2)^-1*(γDL*Laplacian[z[r, t], {r, θ},"Polar"] + (γc*γP*x[r, t]*yT[r, t])/(1 + γP*x[r, t]));
```

Intial/Boundary Conditions:

```
initx = x[r, 0] == 0.;

bc1x = (D[x[r, t], r] == 0) /. r -> dr;

bc2x = x[ρFar, t] == 0.;

inityT = yT[r, 0] == 1.;

initz = z[r, 0] == 0;

bc1z = (D[z[r, t], r] == 0) /. r -> dr;

bc2z = z[ρFar, t] == 0.;
```

Putting it all together:

```
deqns = {dx, dyT, dz, initx, bc1x, bc2x, inityT, initz, bc1z, bc2z};
```

#### Problem

My problem arises for certain parameter values (not all). I have also found that using

```
MaxStepSize -> .1
```

for NDSolveValue seems to help with some instances of my problem, but not all. An example of a "good solution" can be obtained with the following parameters

```
paramsGood = {γDP -> 0.001222, γDL -> 122.2, γa -> 1., γc -> 100., γP -> 0.01, γpL -> 0.01, γL -> 100., γR -> 0.01};


zSoln = NDSolveValue[deqns /. paramsGood, z, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t,0., τmax}, MaxStepSize -> .1];

Plot[zSoln[r, 2.6], {r, dr, 15}, PlotRange -> {-.002, .002}]
```

[image]

However, the following bad parameter set

```
paramsBad = {γDP -> 0.1222, γDL -> 122.2, γa -> 100., γc -> 1., γP -> 0.01, γpL -> 100., γL -> 1000., γR -> 100.};
```

gives an issue in the solution for $z$ (I have picked the time $t=2.6$ to show the bad solution, but the solution doesn't seem good from the start).

```
zSoln = NDSolveValue[deqns /. paramsBad, z, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t,0., τmax}, MaxStepSize -> .1];
Plot[zSoln[r, 2.6], {r, dr, 15}, PlotRange -> {-.002, .002}]
```

[image: badSolution]

None of the dependent variables should be negative.

I have tried modifying the MaxStepSize, StartingStepSize, and specifying a spatial discretization as suggested in the documentation:

```
Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 1000}}}
```

but I cannot seem to fix this issue. Sometimes these things fix the problem, but then for other parameter values the issues come right back (for example, I think making the MinPoints option above larger fixes for this parameter set, but not for all of the. Additionally the solution ends up taking a long time). Why is this happening for the numerical solver, and what is the most efficient way to determine a well-behaved solution Note that I need to be able to solve these equations fairly quickly.

#### Second Problem

If I just change the end time to $t=6.5$ the solution ends up behaving differently. There is a very small response in $z$, but it at least looks well-behaved?

```
zSoln = NDSolveValue[deqns /. paramsBad, z, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t,0., 6.5}, MaxStepSize -> .1];
Plot[zSoln[r, 2.6], {r, dr, 15}, PlotRange -> {-.002, .002}]
```

[image]

Also, this issue does not occur for the "good parameter set"; the solution does not show any notable difference in choice of the final integration time.

So this really makes me question how do I make sure I am getting a legitimate solution here? Which settings should I employ to be confident in my solutions for a wide range of parameters?

Comment: `MaxStepSize -> .1` is not close to providing adequate resolution near `t = 0` and `r = 0` for `paramsBad`.  In fact it really is not adequate for `paramsGood`.  However, just decreasing `MaxStepSize` to .`001` leads to a very slow computation.  I am exploring various options.  I should add that you really need to use `Plot3D` to see whether your answers are reasonable.

Comment: Also, running to `t = 6.5` does not solve the problem either.  It just moves it to a different time slice.  "Why" remains a good question, though.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for looking into it. I tend to use the Manipulate function to move through time rather than Plot3D. But rest assured I'm not just looking at single times.

Comment: Look very near `t = 0`, `r = 0` to see a negative spike even for `tmax = 6.5`  This differs from `tmax = 6.38`, because the temporal zoning changes.  `Use `zSoln["Coordinates"]` to see the zoning..  I shall look at this some more tomorrow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this problem, you must specify a solution method. Since the system of equations is nonlinear and the equation for `y` does not contain derivatives with respect to `r`, we must choose `"MethodOfLines"`. It solves all problems right away. The code contains `Quiet`, since function `xI` is used outside the machine number, for example, `1/2.71828^726.112`is calculated.

```
dr = .001;(*"small" r since we cannot use the origin in polar \
coordinates*)ρFar = 100.;(*r that is "infinity"*)τmax = \
6.38;(*time to solve out to*)
xI = 1/(2*γDP*t + 1)*
   Exp[-(r - dr)^2/(2*(2*γDP*t + 1)) - γa*t];

dx = D[x[r, t], 
    t] == (1 + (γpL*
          yT[r, t])/(1 + γP*x[r, t])^2)^-1*(γDP*
       Laplacian[x[r, t], {r, θ}, "Polar"] + γa*
       xI + γc*γpL/γP*((γP*
            x[r, t])/(1 + γP*x[r, t]))^2*yT[r, t]);

dyT = D[yT[r, t], 
    t] == (-γc*γP*x[r, t]*
      yT[r, t])/(1 + γP*x[r, t]);

dz = D[z[r, t], 
    t] == (1 + γR/(1 + γL*z[r, t])^2)^-1*(γDL*
       Laplacian[z[r, t], {r, θ}, 
        "Polar"] + (γc*γP*x[r, t]*
         yT[r, t])/(1 + γP*x[r, t]));
initx = x[r, 0] == 0.;

bc1x = (D[x[r, t], r] == 0) /. r -> dr;

bc2x = x[ρFar, t] == 0.;

inityT = yT[r, 0] == 1.;

initz = z[r, 0] == 0;

bc1z = (D[z[r, t], r] == 0) /. r -> dr;

bc2z = z[ρFar, t] == 0.;
deqns = {dx, dyT, dz, initx, bc1x, bc2x, inityT, initz, bc1z, bc2z};
paramsGood = {γDP -> 0.001222, γDL -> 
    122.2, γa -> 1., γc -> 100., γP -> 
    0.01, γpL -> 0.01, γL -> 100., γR -> 0.01};


zSoln = NDSolveValue[deqns /. paramsGood, 
    z, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t, 0., τmax}, 
    Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic, 
      "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
      "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
          "MinPoints" -> 137, "MaxPoints" -> 137, 
          "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}}] // Quiet;



paramsBad = {γDP -> 0.1222, γDL -> 122.2, γa -> 
    100., γc -> 1., γP -> 0.01, γpL -> 
    100., γL -> 1000., γR -> 100.};
zSoln1 = NDSolveValue[deqns /. paramsBad, 
    z, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t, 0., τmax}, 
    Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic, 
      "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
      "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
          "MinPoints" -> 137, "MaxPoints" -> 137, 
          "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}}] // Quiet;


zSoln2 = NDSolveValue[deqns /. paramsBad, 
    z, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t, 0., 6.5}, 
    Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic, 
      "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
      "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
          "MinPoints" -> 137, "MaxPoints" -> 137, 
          "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}}] // Quiet;


{Plot3D[zSoln[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, PlotRange -> All,
   PlotLabel -> "paramsGood", AxesLabel -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
 Plot3D[zSoln1[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "paramsBad", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
 Plot3D[zSoln2[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, 6.5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> "paramsBad", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]}
```

[image: Figure 1]
Consider the following example

```
paramsGood = {γDP -> 0.01222, γDL -> 122.2, γa ->
     0.01, γc -> 100., γP -> 1., γpL -> 
    1., γL -> 1000., γR -> 100.}
```

In this case, for `"MaxPoints" -> 137`, the solution goes into region `z<0` (Fig. 2, the upper row on the left). We increase the number of points to 1037 and to 2037 (the top row is the center and to the right). The solution converges. However, with an increase of `"DifferenceOrder" ->4` , the solution looks different (bottom row).This is due to artificial viscosity, which decreases with increasing `"DifferenceOrder"`. I can recommend a combination of options `"MinPoints" -> 1037, "MaxPoints" -> 1037, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2` for such cases (with the number of points you can experiment).
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thank you for this. I had been trying to specify the method, but I guess I was not being specific enough in setting aspects of the method. Which method settings here are the best to tweak if I am still getting some poor solutions? It looks like fewer of my parameter tests are producing bad solutions with your method specification, but I am still getting some bad solutions for other parameter values.

Comment: And I will add that some of the break downs do occur at $r$ values farther from $r=0$ (like from $r\approx2$ to $r\approx8$)

Comment: @AaronStevens Can you write something specific about the parameters.

Comment: `{\[Gamma]DP -> 0.01222, \[Gamma]DL -> 122.2, \[Gamma]a -> 
  0.01, \[Gamma]c -> 100., \[Gamma]P -> 1., \[Gamma]pL -> 
  1., \[Gamma]L -> 1000., \[Gamma]R -> 100.}` I think I have been doing my tests with the same code as in my question. Let me know if everything actually works fine for those parameters. I have been doing many various tests since posting :) Also I removed the MaxStep specification that I had in my post, since your answer does not have it.

Comment: @AaronStevens I definitely don't understand you. What are `bad solutions`?

Comment: Ones where the solution goes negative. Is that parameter set not doing that for you?

Comment: @AaronStevens General rule for the convergence of a numerical solution: the solution does not change with increasing `"MaxPoints"`. Put `"MaxPoints"->1000`, and then `"MaxPoints"->2000` in my code. You will see a beautiful picture that does not change. This means that the numerical solution converges.

Comment: Are you saying the solutions where $z$ goes negative are can valid, so there is something wrong with my equations? The assumptions to arrive at the equations would not allow for negative values.

Comment: @AaronStevens I said that you have a misconception about a numerical solution. See the addition to my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what misconception I was having, but thanks for the addition. I will test it when I can. Although it looks like the bottom right two solutions still go negative?

Comment: @AaronStevens This is due to artificial viscosity, which decreases with increasing "DifferenceOrder".

Comment: Right, but it looks like you are recommending settings that cause the solution to become negative. I guess that's where my confusion is.

Comment: @AaronStevens Sorry, fixed it on `"DifferenceOrder"->2`

Comment: @AlexTrounev  Nicely done (+1).  I did notice that `"IndexReduction" -> Automatic` seems to have no effect.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you, you did well too (+1). I use the option `"IndexReduction" -> Automatic` in all doubtful cases even if it has no effect.

Answer (score 14):

Some experimentation shows that the `NDSolve` problem is associated exclusively with `z` with no feedback to `x` or `yT`, because `dz` and `dyT` are independent of `z`.  It is, therefore, convenient first to compute  `x` and `yT`, and only then to compute `z`.  For `paramsGood`,

```
deqns = {dx, dyT, initx, bc1x, bc2x, inityT};
deqnz = {dz, initz, bc1z, bc2z};

{xSoln, yTSoln} = NDSolveValue[deqns /. paramsGood, {x, yT}, {r, dr, ρFar}, 
    {t, 0., τmax}, MaxStepSize -> .1];
zSoln = NDSolveValue[deqnz /. paramsGood /. {x[r, t] -> xSoln[r, t], yT[r, t] -> yTSoln[r, t]}, 
    z, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t, 0., τmax}, MaxStepSize -> .1];
Plot3D[xSoln[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, t, x}, 
    PlotPoints -> 50, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    ViewPoint -> {-1, -3, 5/4}, ViewVertical -> {1/8, 1/3, 1}]
 Plot3D[yTSoln[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, t, y}, 
    PlotPoints -> 50, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    ViewPoint -> {-1, -3, 5/4}, ViewVertical -> {1/8, 1/3, 1}]
Plot3D[zSoln[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, t, z}, 
    PlotPoints -> 50, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    ViewPoint -> {-1, -3, 5/4}, ViewVertical -> {1/8, 1/3, 1}]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Visibly, the three computed veriables are well behaved everywhere.  A slice through `z` at `t = 2.6` reproduces the first plot in the question, as expected.  The same code applied to `paramsBad` (but with `PlotPoints -> 250`) does not do so well.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Note the spikes near the origin in the plot of `z`.  (The `z` computation in this case also produces a few underflow warnings, which I believe are insignificant.)  Several constant-`r` slices through the `z` plot for very small `r` yield.

```
Plot[Table[zSoln[0.01 n, t], {n, 1, 9, 2}], {t, 0, .04}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, z}]
```

[image]

On the other hand, a plot corresponding to the second plot in the question looks fine, although it may not be.

```
Plot[{zSoln[r, 2.6]}, {r, dr, 15}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, z}]
```

[image]

In any case, the solution for `z` obtained here for `paramsBad` is much better than that in the question, probably because separating the computations of `z` allows `NDSolve` to optimize its automatic time-step determination for `z` alone.

Finally, let us repeat the  computation but with `MaxStepSize -> .01`.  Plots for `x` and `yT` appear identical to those just given, with the `z` plot now seemingly without error.

[image]

But, it isn't.

```
Plot[Table[zSoln[0.01 n, t], {n, 1, 9, 2}], {t, 0, .04}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, z}]
```

[image]

Better, but not  perfect.  Note that the slice for `t = 2.6` changes a bit in this case.

[image]

To answer the specific questions posed by the OP, first the errors obtained for `paramsBad` are due to lack of resolution, largely corrected by reducing `MaxStepSize` to `0.01`.  Still smaller `MaxStepSize` undoubtedly would produce a still more accurate result, but the computation becomes quite slow for `0.001`.  I also experimented some with very small `StartingStepSize`, but obtained little improvement.  Second, the apparent improvement from the second to the third plots in the question are due to different time-steps used by `NDSolve` in the two cases, but plotting `z` in 3D shows that significant errors persist in the computation.  Therefore, little credence should be given to the third plot in the question.

Comment: Thank you for a more thorough look into this. So then, what is my best course of action here? It looks like Solving equations for $x$ and $y_T$ individually first might help a bit, and then reducing the MaxStepSize I suppose?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Do you think it would be worth it to put a bounty and see if other people have suggestions? Or do you think what you have suggested is as far as this can go? I just don't know what else to try.

Comment: Who knows?  @MichaelE2 might have some ideas.

Answer (score 10):

## Fully `NDSolve`-based Solution

Adjustion for spatial step size together with temporal step size helps. I've used parameters mentioned [in the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208030/where-is-the-numerical-solving-breaking-down#comment534492_208201) for testing:

```
mol[n:_Integer|{_Integer..}, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

paramsBad = {γDP -> 0.01222, γDL -> 122.2, γa -> 0.01, γc -> 
    100., γP -> 1., γpL -> 1., γL -> 1000., γR -> 100.};

difforder = 4; points = 200;
test = NDSolveValue[
   deqns /. paramsBad, {x, yT, z}, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t, 0, τmax}, 
   Method -> mol[points, difforder], MaxStepSize -> {Automatic, 0.01}];
Plot3D[test[[-1]][r, t], {r, eps, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

## Partly `NDSolve`-based Solution

Another possible solution is discretizing the system in $r$ direction all by ourselves, in this case `NDSolve` seems to do a better job on choosing temporal step size so we don't need to adjust `MaxStepSize` option. Also, the singularity at $r=0$ is removed i.e. we can use `dr = 0` in this method.

Notice [`pdetoode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) is used for discretization in the following program.

```
Clear[dr]
ρFar = 100.;
τmax = 6.38;
xI = 1/(2 γDP t + 1) Exp[-(r - dr)^2/(2 (2 γDP t + 1)) - γa t];    
dx = D[x[r, t], t] == (1 + (γpL yT[r, t])/(1 + γP x[r, t])^2)^-1 (γDP 
       Laplacian[x[r, t], {r, θ}, "Polar"] + γa 
       xI + γc γpL/γP ((γP x[r, t])/(1 + γP x[r, t]))^2 yT[r, t]);    
dyT = D[yT[r, t], t] == (-γc γP x[r, t] yT[r, t])/(1 + γP x[r, t]);
dz = D[z[r, t], t] == (1 + γR/(1 + γL z[r, t])^2)^-1 (γDL 
       Laplacian[z[r, t], {r, θ}, "Polar"] + (γc γP x[r, t] yT[r, t])/(1 + γP x[r, t]));    
initx = x[r, 0] == 0.;
bc1x = (D[x[r, t], r] == 0) /. r -> dr;
bc2x = x[ρFar, t] == 0.;
inityT = yT[r, 0] == 1.;
initz = z[r, 0] == 0;
bc1z = (D[z[r, t], r] == 0) /. r -> dr;
bc2z = z[ρFar, t] == 0.;
removesingularity = eq \[Function] r # & /@ Expand[eq] // Expand;
{newdx, newdz} = removesingularity /@ {dx, dz};
domain = {dr, ρFar};
points = 100; difforder = 2; grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
ptoofunc = pdetoode[{x, yT, z}[r, t], t, grid, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ode = {del /@ ptoofunc@{newdx, newdz}, ptoofunc@dyT};
odeic = ptoofunc@{initx, inityT, initz};
odebc = With[{sf = 1}, ptoofunc@diffbc[t, sf]@{bc1x, bc2x, bc1z, bc2z}];
var = Outer[#[#2] &, {x, yT, z}, grid];
paramsBad = {γDP -> 0.01222, γDL -> 122.2, γa -> 0.01, γc -> 
    100., γP -> 1., γpL -> 1., γL -> 1000., γR -> 100.};
eps = 0;
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc} /. paramsBad /. dr -> eps, 
   var /. dr -> eps, {t, 0, τmax}];
{solx, soly, solz} = rebuild[#, grid /. dr -> eps, 2] & /@ sollst;
Plot3D[solz[r, t], {r, 0, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

### Remark

1. As one can see, only `100` grid points are used. Increasing `points` won't cause significant difference.
2. Though `difforder = 2` is chosen, `difforder = 4` can be used. You may need to add `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> Solve}` option to `NDSolve` though.
3. Using `dr = 0.001` won't cause any significant difference.

Answer (score 4):

I think a key issue is the inability to resolve your source term, $x_I$, relative to your domain.  Three parameter sets have been given through the course of the discussion.  If we assume that we will use the same spatial and temporal domain for each parameter set, then a `Plot3D` of the source term reveals the relative feature size of the pulse.

```
Plot3D[xI /. paramsGood, {t, 0, τmax}, {r, dr, ρFar}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Source Term paramsGood", 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "DarkBands", 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4]
Plot3D[xI /. paramsBad, {t, 0, τmax}, {r, dr, ρFar}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Source Term paramsBad", 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "DarkBands", 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4]
Plot3D[xI /. paramsBad2, {t, 0, τmax}, {r, dr, ρFar}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Source Term paramsBad2", 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "DarkBands", 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image: Source Term Plot]

As you can see, the first bad parameter set operates on a tiny portion of the domain.  When the ratio of largest relevant feature to the smallest relevant feature that you want to capture is large, discretization can be difficult.  In this case, we can use a helper function to create a non-uniform mesh that is very fine near $r=0$ and expands 100,000 times larger at the end of the domain with 200 grid points.

```
meshGrowth[x0_, xf_, n_, ratio_] := Module[{k, fac, delta},
  k = Log[ratio]/(n - 1);
  fac = Exp[k];
  delta = (xf - x0)/Sum[fac^(i - 1), {i, 1, n - 1}];
  N[{x0}~Join~(x0 + 
      delta Rest@
        FoldList[(#1 + #2) &, 0, 
         PowerRange[fac^0, fac^(n - 3), fac]])~Join~{xf}]
  ]
grid = meshGrowth[0.001, 100, 200, 100000];
ListLogPlot@grid
```

[image: Grid Plot]

We can now apply this non-uniform grid to `NDSolve`. We also note that the source pulse is very short lived for the first parameters set.  We will set the `StartingStepSize` and `MaxStepFraction` to small values to resolve the time domain.  If we apply this to @bbgodfrey's approach, we obtain the following:

```
paramsGood = {γDP -> 0.001222, γDL -> 
    122.2, γa -> 1., γc -> 100., γP -> 
    0.01, γpL -> 0.01, γL -> 100., γR -> 0.01};
paramsBad = {γDP -> 0.1222, γDL -> 122.2, γa -> 
    100., γc -> 1., γP -> 0.01, γpL -> 
    100., γL -> 1000., γR -> 100.};
paramsBad2 = {γDP -> 0.01222, γDL -> 122.2, γa ->
     0.01, γc -> 100, γP -> 1, γpL -> 
    1., γL -> 1000., γR -> 100.};
dr = .001;(*"small" r since we cannot use the origin in polar \
coordinates*)
ρFar = 100.;(*r that is "infinity"*)
τmax = 6.38;(*time to solve out to*)
opts = (Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "Coordinates" -> {grid}}});
{xSolnG, yTSolnG} = 
  NDSolveValue[
   deqns /. paramsGood, {x, yT}, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t, 
    0., τmax}, opts, StartingStepSize -> 0.0001, 
   MaxStepFraction -> 1/400];
zSolnG = NDSolveValue[
   deqnz /. paramsGood /. {x[r, t] -> xSolnG[r, t], 
     yT[r, t] -> yTSolnG[r, t]}, 
   z, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t, 0., τmax}, opts, 
   StartingStepSize -> 0.0001, MaxStepFraction -> 1/400];
Plot3D[xSolnG[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, PlotRange -> All,
  AxesLabel -> {r, t, x}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 ViewPoint -> {-1, -3, 5/4}, ViewVertical -> {1/8, 1/3, 1}]
Plot3D[yTSolnG[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, t, y}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 ViewPoint -> {-1, -3, 5/4}, ViewVertical -> {1/8, 1/3, 1}]
Plot3D[zSolnG[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, PlotRange -> All,
  AxesLabel -> {r, t, z}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 ViewPoint -> {-1, -3, 5/4}, ViewVertical -> {1/8, 1/3, 1}]

{xSolnB, yTSolnB} = 
  NDSolveValue[
   deqns /. paramsBad, {x, yT}, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t, 
    0., τmax}, opts, StartingStepSize -> 0.0001, 
   MaxStepFraction -> 1/400];
zSolnB = NDSolveValue[
   deqnz /. paramsBad /. {x[r, t] -> xSolnB[r, t], 
     yT[r, t] -> yTSolnB[r, t]}, 
   z, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t, 0., τmax}, opts, 
   StartingStepSize -> 0.0001, MaxStepFraction -> 1/400];
Plot3D[xSolnB[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, PlotRange -> All,
  AxesLabel -> {r, t, x}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 ViewPoint -> {-1, -3, 5/4}, ViewVertical -> {1/8, 1/3, 1}]
Plot3D[yTSolnB[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, t, y}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 ViewPoint -> {-1, -3, 5/4}, ViewVertical -> {1/8, 1/3, 1}]
Plot3D[zSolnB[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, PlotRange -> All,
  AxesLabel -> {r, t, z}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 ViewPoint -> {-1, -3, 5/4}, ViewVertical -> {1/8, 1/3, 1}]

{xSolnB2, yTSolnB2} = 
  NDSolveValue[
   deqns /. paramsBad2, {x, yT}, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t, 
    0., τmax}, opts, StartingStepSize -> 0.0001, 
   MaxStepFraction -> 1/400];
zSolnB2 = 
  NDSolveValue[
   deqnz /. paramsBad2 /. {x[r, t] -> xSolnB2[r, t], 
     yT[r, t] -> yTSolnB2[r, t]}, 
   z, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t, 0., τmax}, opts, 
   StartingStepSize -> 0.0001, MaxStepFraction -> 1/400];
Plot3D[xSolnB2[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, t, x}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 ViewPoint -> {-1, -3, 5/4}, ViewVertical -> {1/8, 1/3, 1}]
Plot3D[yTSolnB2[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, t, y}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 ViewPoint -> {-1, -3, 5/4}, ViewVertical -> {1/8, 1/3, 1}]
Plot3D[zSolnB2[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, t, z}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 ViewPoint -> {-1, -3, 5/4}, ViewVertical -> {1/8, 1/3, 1}]

Plot[Table[zSolnG[0.01 n, t], {n, 1, 9, 2}], {t, 0, .04}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, z}, PlotLabel -> "Good"]
Plot[Table[zSolnB[0.01 n, t], {n, 1, 9, 2}], {t, 0, .04}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, z}, PlotLabel -> "Bad"]
Plot[Table[zSolnB2[0.01 n, t], {n, 1, 9, 2}], {t, 0, .04}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, z}, PlotLabel -> "Bad2"]
```

[image: bbgodfrey plot]

We can also apply this non-uniform mesh to you original set of coupled equations for the first bad (i.e., sharpest pulse) parameter set and it seems to still hold together.

```
deqns = {dx, dyT, dz, initx, bc1x, bc2x, inityT, initz, bc1z, bc2z};
zSolnorig = 
  NDSolveValue[deqns /. paramsBad, 
   z, {r, dr, ρFar}, {t, 0., τmax}, opts, 
   StartingStepSize -> 0.0001, MaxStepFraction -> 1/400];
Plot[zSolnorig[r, 2.6], {r, dr, 15}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot3D[zSolnorig[r, t], {r, dr, 15}, {t, 0, τmax}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, t, z}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 ViewPoint -> {-1, -3, 5/4}, ViewVertical -> {1/8, 1/3, 1}]
```

[image: Coupled Solution]

By resolving the time and spatial domains of the source pulse, we have substantially eliminated negative values.

Comment: Nice analysis (+1).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I thought your decoupling was quite insightful (+1).